# Unable to send bitcoin from bitcoin core wallet

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, sending

Using bitcoin core wallet fully synchronized with the blockchain on ubuntu

[image: attempting to send]

I click on "send".  Nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending to a bech32 address. The current release of Bitcoin Core does not support bech32 addresses. The address box highlighted in read indicates that the address is invalid to the wallet.

---

The next release of Bitcoin Core will support sending to bech32 addresse as well as full Segwit wallet support.